# I want to find distance from one location to another locations and find nearest locations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

I am getting this error

```
error: function st_distancesphere(geography, geometry) does not exist
```

i am stuck on this,i am using sequalize js orm
and i am using this query what i am doing wrong!!!

```
    var location = sequelize.literal(`st_geomfromtext('POINT(${aLat} ${aLng})')`);
    var distance = sequelize.fn('st_distancesphere',
        sequelize.literal('location::geometry'), location)
    provider
        .findAll({
            attributes: [[distance, 'distance']],
            where: sequelize.where(distance, { [Op.lte]: 10000 }),
   logging: console.log,
        })

location                                            lat       lng     
0101000020E6100000A913D044D8C03640DA1B7C6132F95240 |22.7533 | 75.8937
0101000020E6100000EF38454772B93640CD3B4ED191F85240 | 22.7244 | 75.8839
```

Comment: now i updated my code you can see also i am not geeting error it just return []

Comment: Can you please also add what final SQL query is generated after executing the function

Comment: Also can you mention some sample data that is  present in location column of your table and its data type

Comment: @AbhishekShah @Jim jones my query is below
`SELECT st_distancesphere(location::geometry, st_geomfromtext('POINT(23.1765 75.7885)')) AS "distance" FROM "providers" AS "provider" WHERE st_distancesphere(location::geometry, st_geomfromtext('POINT(23.1765 75.7885)')) <= 10000`

Comment: also added location data above so you can check

Comment: Now what ts happened  that the query gives distance in degree unit or something called projection unit so how can i convert to get in meters,km

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76968

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the function is actually available in your release version. As stated [in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/375281), this could easily be your problem.

Comment: `SELECT PostGIS_Version();  postgis_version
---------------------------------------
         2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1`
Yes i checked see above now what ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest, no function named **st_distancesphere** exist for the argument type ***(geography, geometry)***

- Well the documentation for **st_distancesphere** says: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html - it needs 2 `geometry` datatypes.
- And the error says that you tried to call it with *(**geography**, geometry)*. So I assume the
  `sequelize.literal('location')` is what you want to reference a column named `location` in your table which is of datatype `geography`.
- So the only thing to be done is to convert the location column to type - `geometry`.  Referring [this SO post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18011/converting-from-geography-to-geometry-data-type-in-postgis)

```js
var location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${75.8577} ${22.7196})')`);
var distance = sequelize.fn(
    'ST_DistanceSphere',
    sequelize.literal('location::geometry'),
    location
);
provider
    .findAll({
        attributes: [[distance, 'distance']],
        where: sequelize.where(distance, { [Op.lte]: 10 }),
        order: [
            [sequelize.literal('"distance"'), 'ASC'], // for smallest distance at top
        ],
    })
```

The final query should come out to be something like:

```sql
SELECT
  st_distancesphere(location :: geometry, st_geomfromtext('POINT(75.8577 22.7196)' )) AS distance 
FROM
  provider 
WHERE
  st_distancesphere(location :: geometry, st_geomfromtext('POINT(75.8577 22.7196)' )) <= 10 
ORDER BY
  "distance" ASC;
```

Comment: ok god bless you but it not works when i giving lat lng 
`SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(location::geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(75.8937 22.7533)')) AS "distance" FROM "providers" AS "provider" WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(location::geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(75.8937 22.7533)')) <= 10000;
` is it correct

Comment: Please add new things you did as an update in your question, and please also add the latest error that you get...Thanks

Comment: This time query is working fine it didn't get any result if i'm giving like 75.8937 22.7533 this lng , lat in request and my stored db lat lng is 22 or 21, 74 or 75.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing `geometry` and `geography` parameters in the same function. [`ST_DistanceSphere`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html) expects two `geometries`, and one of your parameters is a `geography`. Either use two `geometry` parameters with `ST_DistanceSpehre` or two `geography` with [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) - it will depend on your use case.

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(
         'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.56 54.17)'::geometry,
         'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.49 54.15)'::geometry),
      ST_Distance( -- computed over a spheroid
         'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.56 54.17)'::geography, 
         'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.49 54.15)'::geography);


 st_distancesphere |  st_distance  
-------------------+---------------
      5071.1616871 | 5085.78620104
(1 Zeile)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ee138314a254ffd5f83a9b189a4a76f)

Comment: can you give sequalize query for above psql query so that i can proceed @jim jones 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the psql query which is worked for me below given

```sql
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(location::geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(42.28787 -71.064544)',4326)) AS "distance" 
FROM 
  "providers" AS "provider" 
WHERE ST_Distance(location::geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(42.28787 -71.064544)',4326)) <= 10000000 
ORDER BY 
  "distance" ASC;
```

this is the sequalize query which i am created

```js
var location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${aLat} ${aLng})',4326)`);
    var distance = sequelize.fn('ST_Distance',
        sequelize.literal('location::geometry'), location)
    provider.findAll({ attributes: [[distance, 'distance']], where: sequelize.where(distance, { [Op.lte]: 10000000 }),order: [   [sequelize.literal('"distance"'), 'ASC'], // for smallest distance at top
            ],
        })
```

this is result which i get from query but its not gives distance in m,km,miles what to do

```json
 "data": [
        {
            "distance": 148.24498154225
        },
        {
            "distance": 148.250885004604
        }
    ]
```